# How can I line break OHAttributedLabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

How can I line break [OHAttributedLabel](http://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)? My below code didn't work.

```
OHAttributedLabel *lbl = [[OHAttributedLabel alloc] init];
lbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending a standard line break (\n, \r, \r\n, Unicode paragraph separator) to the attributedText property should do the trick.

Comment: The text is not known in advance and I don't know where to put the Unicode paragraph separators, for this I need to use property lineBreakMode

Comment: In that case, from the documentation UILineBreakModeTailTruncation will Truncate the text when it overflows, what you want to use instead is UILineBreakModeWordWrap.

Comment: Weird, the documentation for `UILabel` says that `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` is the default but this worked for me too. Maybe `OHAttributedLabel` uses a different default.